# SQL Server 2008: Calculate SUM in new row (group by)

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum

I have a table with following:

```
CREATE TABLE #tableA (color varchar(10), ids int, scores int)
INSERT INTO #tableA 
VALUES ('red', 1, 100),
('red',2,100),
('red',3,50),
('blue',1,20),
('blue',5,50)
```

I want to get the SUM of scores ,group by color. Expected result:

```
color  id  scores
red    1   100
red    2   100
red    3    50
           SUM 250 (100+100+50)  
blue   1    20
blue   5    50
            SUM 70 (all blues)
```

Thanks

Comment: Usually this would be done with two separate statements - SQL is used for building result sets, not for displaying them in a report with totals.  That would be the job of the report software, such as SSRS.

Comment: Well, based on the two good answers I guess I stand corrected :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUPING SETS` for this, although the results won't be directly in the format you want:

```
SELECT  color, 
        ids, 
        SUM(scores) Scores
FROM #TableA
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((color,ids),(color))
```

The results are:

```
╔═══════╦══════╦════════╗
║ color ║ ids  ║ Scores ║
╠═══════╬══════╬════════╣
║ blue  ║ 1    ║     20 ║
║ blue  ║ 5    ║     50 ║
║ blue  ║ NULL ║     70 ║
║ red   ║ 1    ║    100 ║
║ red   ║ 2    ║    100 ║
║ red   ║ 3    ║     50 ║
║ red   ║ NULL ║    250 ║
╚═══════╩══════╩════════╝
```

Comment: Is there a way to alias the `null` with something meaningful like `SubTotal` etc within SQL ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`ROllUP`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx) in `Group by`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT color,
               ids,
               Sum(scores)scores
        FROM   #tableA
        GROUP  BY color,
                  ids WITH rollup) a
WHERE  color IS NOT NULL
        OR ids IS NOT NULL
```